# CSS: apply formatting to tag contents only

Tags: html, css, formatting

Normally CSS classes change formatting of tags themselves. For example a following code

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.r {background-color:green; color:white; font-weight:bold}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li class="r">Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li class="r">Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

makes items with "r" class to appear without a bullet and with background-color to whole page width.

How to apply formatting not to the tag itself, but to contents only (to text in this case) **WITHOUT HAVING TO PUT AN ADDITIONAL TAG INSIDE** ?

Comment: What formatting would you like to apply to the contents of the tag?  Styles like `font-weight:bold` already apply to only the text contents.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot format tags in CSS at all; you can only format elements. (You cannot format the tag `<ul>`, for example, but you can format an element that is marked up using the tags `<ul>` and `</ul>` and content between them.)

So you seem to be asking how to style the content of an element instead of styling the element itself, without inserting an inner element. The general answer is that you can’t. This does not mean that the inner element needs to be written in HTML markup; it could also be inserted dynamically with JavaScript. For example, the following simplistic code inserts an inner `div` element into each `li` element on the page and uses an accordingly modified selector in CSS:

```
<style>
.r > .item-content {
  background-color:green; color:white; font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].innerHTML = '<div class=item-content>' + li[i].innerHTML + '</div>';
  }
}
</script>
```

In the special case described, the specific issue is that the `color` property of a `li` element affects the list marker (bullet), too, in addition to the element content. This could be handled in special cases using the [`:first-line`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-line-pseudo) pseudo-element, using `.r:first-line` instead of just `.r`. This would make `color: white` apply only to the first line of the element content, so the list bullet would not be affected. However, the width of the pseudo-element is just what is occupied by the characters on the line, not the available width as for `li`. And of course the approah would style the item wrong when it is divided into two or more lines.

Apart from `:first-line` and `:first-letter`, there is no way in CSS as currently defined and implemented to refer to the content or part of the content of an element, when it does not constitute in an inner element.

Answer (score -1):

```
ul li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold
}
```

Comment: This does not address the question asked. It addresses a completely different question (about how to style the even-numbered items without using `class` attributes).